# Async file downloader android

Tags: java, android

I started creating file downloader class. Here is what i have:

```
public class Downloader {

    //download url
    URL url;

    public Downloader(URL downloadURL){
        url = downloadURL;
    }


      public void toFile(File fName) {
            try {

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                urlConnection.connect();

                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(fName);

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;

                while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

                }

                fileOutput.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }




}
```

I need to call this downloader in new thread. Maybe someone could give me hint why i need to call new thread or asyc task for this.

```
public void downloadFile(String urlToDownload,String path) throws MalformedURLException{




        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Downloader(new URL(urlToDownload)).toFile(new File(path));

                 }


          }).start();
}
```

So when i want to downlaod my file it's strating downloading asynchronical.

I don't really want that.
 I want to create downloader where i could choose if i want  synchronously or async download a file.

But in the first place, i want to know when file was downloaded. How could i know this ?

Maybe someone had done this and could help me.
I need to know when file is downloaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can't download anything on the main thread, you get an Application Not Responding dialog in versions < 3.0, and in 3.0 and higher simply get an exception.
2. Your current approach is nearly right.
3. If you want to publish progress of downloading and notify UI about the finished downloading you can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to notify any application component about the finished downloading.

Answer (score 2):

1. It start when thread start, after you call start(). For convenience usually using Asyntask like [matemink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/976408/matemink) solution:

   +method doInBackground() will run in worker thread

   +method onPostExecute(0 will run to update UI thread
2. For your concern:

   > I need to call this downloader in new thread. Maybe someone could give
   >   me hint why i need to call new thread or asyc task for this

**Answer**:
You need download in separate thread or Asyntask to avoid ANR dialog̣ ̣(in case you need download big file or your network connection is slow it can cause ANR dialog in Main UI thread), that is why you need to put high workload implement in worker thread rather than Main UI thread:

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to know when your file has been downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Still use AsyncTask, and use onProgressUpdate method.

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cant perform network operation in the main thread.
You can look up to this repository to download file.
[AndroidFileDownloaderModule](https://github.com/amit-appstudioz/AndroidFileDownloaderModule)

Comment: Better to post a solution rather than a link which might not exist anymore later on.